Accessing a function in a child object from its parent
I have some UserControls (usercontrol1, usercontrol2, ...), and I am accessing the currently shown one as the type of UserControl, so I don't know which one it is. I have a function inside each one of them, and I want to call that function.
The way I'm currently handling this is by setting an ID in the Tag property for each one of them and then using the switch statement:
switch(Tag.ToString())
{
    case "1":
        usercontrol1.function();
        break;
    case "2":
        usercontrol2.function();
        break;
}

But I'm planning to have lots of these user controls. So is this the way everybody does it or is there a better way?
More specific explanation:
I have a button inside a user control (InnerUsrCntrl), and when I press it, it should call a function in another user control (ParentUsrCntrl). I can reach that user control like this:
 ParentUsrCntrl = InnerUsrCntrl.Parent.Parent;

However I wouldn't be able to call the ParentUsrCntrl.Function() unless I convert its type from Control to usercontrol1 or usercontrol2 ... etc. So I want an easier method to do that than the one I am currently using.

Interface

You need an Interface and implement it on your UserControls. Now you just need to convert Parent into this Interface and call Function.
